# How to kill/stop a running process in a terminal without losing its output?

Tags: c++, bash, terminal, output

I try to run a simple c++ code in a terminal and try to store its output in output.txt.

CODE-

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    while(1)
    {
        cin>>n;
        cout<<n;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

using a terminal commands:

```
g++ code.cpp
./a.out > output.txt
```

and input:

```
1 
2
3
4
5
```

but when I terminate the program by Ctrl+C, output.txt is empty.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: try with  cout << n <<std::endl

Comment: If the output is not flushed every time you print, `std::cout << n << std::flush;` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me even it is working as you expect. I think maybe your task is not closed! so try two things:
1- try to close the terminal after crtl+C. after again check the content of output file
2- please give a good name instead of a.out(testfile.out) and after crtl+c try below command in shell:

```
sudo ps -aux | grep testfile
```

to see that your process either was killed or not

Answer (score -1):

I just check it out, I terminated the program by Ctrl+C, the output is perfectly storing into output.txt file.

But still, if you are not sure about the problem you can use the below method:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    while(n!=-1){
        cin>>n;
        if(n!=-1)
            cout<<n<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input -1 to terminate the program. :)